# Variable concatenation

Tags: bash

I've 3 dates(could be more) taking as arguments as:

```
DATE_0="01-JAN-11"
DATE_1="01-JAN-12"
DATE_2="01-JAN-13"
```

Now I want to loop on dates and want to append values after _ by another variable.

```
for (( i=0; i<3; i++ ))
do
    echo $DATE_$i
done
```

I want when i=0 when it should print 01-JAN-11, when i=1 then print 01-JAN-12 and so on. Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 3):

You can use indirect parameter expansion

```
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    var=DATE_$i
    echo ${!var}
done
```

but an array is a better solution

```
DATES=(01-JAN-11 01-JAN-12 01-JAN-13)
for d in "${DATES[@]}"; do
   echo $d
done
```

or

```
for ((i=0; i<${#DATES[@]}; i++)); do
   echo ${DATES[i]}
done
```

Comment: for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    var=DATE_$i
    echo ${!var}
done

This worked for me :) 
thanks chepner.